# Floating an element on top in XUL

Tags: positioning, z-index, xul

I am trying to create an auto-complete suggestion interface in a XUL window.

I have a `<textbox>` that I am generating suggestions for upon keypress and creating a `<box>` with the list of suggestions (`<label>`s).  At the moment the `<box>` is displayed in-line as the next element after the `<textbox>` but that is pushing the rest of the window's content below the fold (i.e. disappears off-screen).

How can I create a suggestion list (much like StackOverflow uses for tags) that **floats over the other content in the window**?  If that's not possible, a way to resize the window to include the new content or provide scrollbars would do.

Answer (score 1):

A `<textbox type="autocomplete">` uses a `<panel>` to display its suggestions. (Depending on what you need the autocomplete to be able to do, you might find that using an autocomplete textbox is easier than trying to create a custom textbox.)